# Spring Injection with JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, maven

I'got a problem with Injecting Beans with annotations using the springframework in a JSF Project.
I think I did exactly what basically every Tutorial I've found so far says I should do but when I publish my war to tomcat and try to use the loginService from the LoginBean I get a NullPointerException. Any Ideas?

my Bean (shortened):

```
package de.homer.server.config.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.homer.server.config.user.LoginService;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

        @Autowired
        LoginService loginService;

    public final String doLogin() {
        // try to use loginService here
        // if I set breakpoint here I can see that loginService is null
    }

}
```

my service (shortened):

```
package de.homer.server.config.user;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LoginService {

}
```

my applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.homer.server.config.beans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.homer.server.config.user" />
</beans>
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>homeR</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <!-- Spring context -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">
<faces-config>
    <application>
        <variable-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
        </variable-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

and if it matters an excerpt of my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

last but not least a part of the log:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner  - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/stonedsquirrel/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/homeR-server-runtime/WEB-INF/classes/de/homer/server/config/user/LoginService.class]
...
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'loginService'
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'loginService'
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Eagerly caching bean 'loginService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'loginService'
```

and the stack trace:

```
WARNING: #{loginBean.doLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginBean.doLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.homer.server.config.beans.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 25 more

Jan 16, 2012 9:42:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/homer] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.homer.server.config.beans.LoginBean.doLogin(LoginBean.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Done, was the one thing I forgot ;-)

Comment: @stonedsquirrel can you post the statement where you're getting the null pointer ? My understanding is that loginService is not autowired and hence is null. Am I correct ?

Comment: @AravindA you are correct. I can debug the doLogin() method and see that loginService is null. Thought that was clear. Sorry!

Comment: OK, I slowly start to get pissed at spring. With the same Code as above I get a different Error. This time not even the Bean does resolve. Error is "Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null" in the JSF. At last now the Error is consistent. May be an issue with tomcat republishing properly that it worked partially before. Should I edit my question or is this comment enough? I'm kind of new here ;-) Sorry to bother you guys!

Comment: Alright, if I add the ManagedBean Tag to LoginBean it is initialized in the JSF and I get the NullPointer again. Makes sense cause the ManagedBean is loaded in the Facelet context and is ignoring the spring context. This way the error makes sense. But still: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it. Turns out it was a problem with a deprecated version of faces-config.xml
It works with this config:

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

the Bean:

```
package de.homer.server.config.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.homer.server.config.user.LoginService;

@Component
@Scope("session")
@Qualifier("loginBean")
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    public final String doLogin() {
    // try to use loginService here
    // if I set breakpoint here I can see that loginService is null
    }

}
```

the service:

```
package de.homer.server.config.user;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class LoginService {

}
```

thanks for all your inspiration!

Comment: Where is import for @Qualifier ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove Autowired option:

Define your Service and DAO beans here;

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public LoginService loginService() {
        return new LoginService();
    }
}
```

Initializes Beans,

```
@Configuration
@Import( { PersistenceHibernateConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, ApplicationConfig.class } )
public class SpringMainConfig{

}
```

Add this param to web.xml,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.ecs.esr.spring.conf.SpringMainConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Add this to manage bean constructor,

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
loginService = ctx.getBean(LoginService.class);
```

Comment: OK, I guess this would work but it's what I want to avoid. A lot of Tutorials and Forums suggest that it is possible with autowiring. If I have to initialize the Bean in each constructor I could just make LoginService Singleton and set it without spring. The advantage of using spring seems to get lost here. Or am I missing something? Again thanks for the answer.